# CDC for 100 tables in TalenD

Tags: mysql, oracle, sql-server-2008, talend, change-data-capture

I am new to CDC, have a query. I have say 100 tables where i cannot create a subscribers for 100 tables to capture the data change using TalenD. Is their any way to capture for all the tables dynamically without manual creation of the subscribers and also tables wont have timestamp column in it. Database could be anything.

Thanks in advance
Manikandan

Comment: First, which DBMS are you working with? All of them? Second, your question is unintelligible.

Comment: For eg: i have 100 tables in mysql, need to capture the changed data and store it on another database MsSQL using TalenD.

Comment: So, what you want is a sort of AUDIT that would record any changed made to any table, right? If this is the case, you need to define **TRIGGERS** to all tables and have the action of the trigger to record which table was changed (i.e. addition, deletion, update) into an AUDIT table.

Comment: Thanks. How can we achieve this in TalenD. Because in TalenD we are creating a subscriber for auditing the Tables but i need to create the subscriber for all 100 tables. Is their any way to dynamically create subscribers for 100 tables.

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable about TalenD and hence cannot make any suggestion. The only contribution I can offer is what I wrote about triggers (which is the standard database mechanism normally used for AUDIT implementations). Last, if my comments were useful for you, it would be nice that you up-mark them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the following link helpful

https://help.talend.com/display/TalendDataIntegrationStudioUserGuide61EN/10.3.1+How+to+set+up+CDC+in+Trigger+mode

Comment: Thanks for the post pradeep. But i use TalenD Real-Time BigData enterprise edition, in that i am not able to see the Options like trigger/X Stream mode while creating a subscriber.